# Is there anyway to get the inputted password string from the login form?

Tags: login, password, wp-login-form

Is there anyway to get the password string from the login form?

Comment: It would be a huge security hole if there were.

Comment: @vancoder, you would be right if the user was asking how to retrieve the unhashed password from the DB, but the plaintext is seen when the user initially sets their password. That's how any plugin that enforces a level of password security functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job, just add it to `functions.php` or put in a plugin:

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'my_authenticate_user', 10, 2 );

function my_authenticate_user( $user, $password ) {

    // do whatever you want with the $password variable here

    return $user;

}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what are you using it for?

Comment: Well, it does get the password from the login form, but does not get the password string, when someone updates their password. Any idea how to get that?
I mainly need the password from the update profile form. I need to send this passowrd string to an external API, to update password for that user in an external system at the same time.

Comment: the only way i can see to do this is to hook into the `user_profile_update_errors` action (line 153 of `wp-admin/includes/user.php`). the plaintext password is stored in `$user->user_pass` (if it has been set), but you'll need to check that there are no password errors.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the form markup:

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
```

So `$_POST['pwd']` is the password.